# How to bind the name of the active TabItem to a Label in WPF?

Tags: wpf, binding, tabcontrol, tabitem

actual the Labels shows the namespace of the control and not the name (header) of the active tabitem.

```
..
<Label Content="{x:Type TabControl}" />
</Grid>

<TabControl>

    <TabItem Header="Header1" />
    <TabItem Header="Header2" />
    ..
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You obviously have no clue about what you are doing, read this: [Data Binding Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx)
The [`x:Type` markup extension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753322.aspx) has nothing to do with binding, it just returns the type of a given class.

---

One way to bind to the selected item:

```
<Label Content="{Binding ElementName=tc, Path=SelectedItem.Header}"/>
<TabControl Name="tc" ...>
     <!-- Items -->
</TabControl>
```

(*Note: The `SelectedItem` normally (- when using `ItemsSource` -) does not represent the selected control but the data behind the selected item*)

Comment: Bad form, mate! The first 10 words of the answer were unnecessary and rude. Focus on the answer, not your personal opinion of the skills of the person asking it.

Comment: @CobaltBlue Well, a lot of things are strictly speaking not necessary and whether something is rude is dependent on the recipient. Sure, it probably could have been worded differently, but i think the comment serves a purpose regardless. For long term success a proper understanding of the fundamental principles is much more useful than being fed a solution to an immediate problem at hand. I wanted to make clear that the OP essentially had a much bigger problem here than what the question states.

Answer (score 5):

I hope this is what you want -

```
<TabControl x:Name="MyControl">
    <TabItem Header="tab1" />
    <TabItem Header="tab2" />
    <TabItem Header="tab3" />
</TabControl>
<!-- ... -->
<Label Content="{Binding ElementName=MyControl, Path=SelectedItem.Header}"/>
```